# Finding printers that work with Web Bluetooth

Tags: printing, bluetooth, label, thermal-printer, web-bluetooth

I would like to print to thermal receipt and label printers through the web (PWA) on Android devices.

In this page you can see some example code:
https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/demos/blob/gh-pages/bluetooth-printer/index.html

Is it possible to print to "any" bluetooth enabled thermal printer or is there some process to determine which bluetooth receipt and label printers are compatible.

My worry is that some printers will only work with provided sdk's that are only written for java/objective-c/swift.

Comment: The printer might expect the document in a specific format you can't reproduce without the provided sdk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately from what I have seen it takes a bit of investigation into an individual model of thermal printer to figure out whether it supports Bluetooth LE (as opposed to Bluetooth Classic) and to learn what dialect of printer control language it speaks (ESC/POS, ZPL, etc.). I recommend asking the manufacturer for detailed documentation (in case you have to build your own library) and letting them know that you are looking for something you can interface with using Web Bluetooth. If enough customers ask for it maybe they'll start advertising compatibility and even produce SDKs.

Comment: Did exactly what you said thankyou! They sent me a technical command manual with ESC/POS, CPCL, TSPL and a whole bunch of stuff for printing barcodes but it seems to have everything needed to create a binary "packet". I'll have to build my own library since their engineers hadn't heard of web-bluetooth.  

My thoughts are html -> html2canvas -> canvas -> canvas.toDataURL() -> converter -> binary -> bluetooth is probably the easiest way to print anything.. that way I can design any receipts in html (text wrap etc) and hopefully have the printout look exactly the same.

Comment: Sadly the customer currently has over 100 ipads that this won't work for because Apple doesn't support web-bluetooth.

Comment: There are actually a couple options for "Web Bluetooth browsers" available in the App Store that provide implementations of the API.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as you probably know iOS doesn't support other browsers adding to homescreen which makes it very hard to implement a POS app.

Comment: To my knowledge, the WebBluetooth API only supports BLE devices (and NOT Bluetooth Classic). For the pour souls buying and trying printers, the Star Micronics SP700 is NOT compatible with WebBluetooth, as it does not use BLE.

Comment: Which model did you get? Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

usb_thermal_printer_web: This package helps you to connect to your thermal usb printer via USB in Flutter Web and print. It has been tested in MP583 thermal printer.

https://pub.dev/packages/usb_thermal_printer_web